# GSSException:Failure unspecified at GSS-API (Mechanism level: Encryption type AES256CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96 is not supported/enabled)using spnego

Tags: java, encryption, kerberos, spnego, keytab

I am facing the below mentioned issue when I try authenticating to Kerberos using a keytab file.

GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Encryption type AES256CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96 is not supported/enabled)

I have followed the steps mentioned on http://spnego.sourceforge.net/pre_flight.html and http://spnego.sourceforge.net/server_keytab.html to setup the complete environment.

Below are my conf files,

krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]

    default_tkt_enctypes = aes128-cts aes256-cts

    default_tgs_enctypes = aes128-cts aes256-cts

    permitted_enctypes   = aes128-cts aes256-cts

[realms]

ATHENA.LOCAL  = {

     kdc = cerberus.athena.local 

     default_domain = ATHENA.LOCAL 
}

[domain_realm]

    .ATHENA.LOCAL = ATHENA.LOCAL
```

login.conf

```
spnego-client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required;
};

spnego-server {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    storeKey=true
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="file:///E:/tomcat-7.0.55/bin/test.keytab"
    isInitiator=false;
};

custom-client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    storeKey=true
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="file:///E:/tomcat-7.0.55/bin/test.keytab"
    principal=zeus;
};
```

Can someone tell me the solution to get out of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are locking down the allowed encryption types in your krb5.conf to only allow the AES128 encryption types while you want to do AES256, so that's one problem.
2. At the very bottom of your krb5.conf the last line is wrong.  Should be  .athena.local=ATHENA.LOCAL  (Ref:   http://web.mit.edu/KERBEROS/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5.4/doc/krb5-admin/Sample-krb5_002econf-File.html)
3. If your keytab actually has support for AES256 encryption types in it, then the Directory account to which the keytab is related also must be enabled to support AES256 encryption types.  There's a checkbox for this if you are using Active Directory.
4. You must have an SPN registered for the service you are trying to authenticate to in the Directory/Kerberos database.  If it's an HTTP service, it would look something like:  HTTP/server1.athena.local
5. You'll need the Java jurisdiction unlimited strength policy files present on your server to decrypt AES256 encryption.
6. Last but not least, you didn't specify what Directory service you are using Kerberos with.  Is it Active Directory?  Red Hat IdM? OpenDirectory?  Heimdal Kerberos.  Not a lot to go on here.

Comment: Hi @Arjun, not sure what you meant by just "LDAP" regarding #6.  And what about points #1-5?

Comment: Hi @todd, for point 1 & 3, we tried both AES128 and AES256, but still no success. for point 4, SPN is registered. for point 5, I will try it. for point 6, we are using LDAP which is similar to AD with kerberos.

Comment: Hi @todd, after doing point number 5, i am getting a different error, below is the error message,                                              GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96)
        sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:788)

Comment: At this point, it sounds like you may have forgetten to include AES256-SHA1 encryption support inside your keytab, based ont he error thrown.  Can you post the command you used to create your keytab?